# How to create a new branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch, visual-studio-2015

I see this has been "answered" a few times before... but when inside **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**, there appears to be **no way of creating a branch by right clicking on the solution**.

**How do I create a new branch in TFS**. *I come from GIT if that helps to explain to me.*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Explorer

Right click on the solution / item you want to branch -> Branching and Merging

Note: For this to work your solution must already be in TFS.